Client Secret Missing on Google Developer Console for iOS
I want to use google to sign in to my iOS app. So I registered my application on the Google Developer Console and created credentials for OAuth 2.0 for iOS.
Everything worked the same as the how to guides but when I finished creating the credentials only the Client ID was given to me and no Client Secret. I attached a screenshot to show the missing Client Secret.
enter image description here
I also tried downloading the OAuth Client file and it also only shows the same info.
I Also waited a day to see if the fields would take some time to populate.
I can't find any other info on the internet to try since they all say the client secret should be listed there. So I was hoping someone on stack overflow might know.

It's not missing. It's like that by design. think about it, if you put a secret in a mobile app's source code, it will be visible to everyone since you have to distribute the entire app which can be decompiled.
For mobile apps, native apps and single-page applications, OAuth 2.0 should work without a client secret. you will use the authorization code flow. All OAuth 2.0 client libraries should have this working out of the box.

Thanks that makes sense. I just wish the google docs didn't say the opposite lol

Reece, I had exactly the same question as you. Did it work without the secret?

If you are using AWS Auth then it requires the client secret.  So although it isn't needed for some experiences, it still is required by AWS auth.
